# complex numbers - proof of this statement

Tags: complex-numbers, proof-writing, problem-solving

i am trying to prove this statement, i dont but how to start.

$$\forall z,w \in \mathbb{C}\quad  |z|^2+|w|^2=\frac{1}{2}(|z+w|^2+|z-w|^2)$$

can someone please show me how start?

Comment: Use that $|x|^2 = x \cdot \overline{x}$ and distribute all multiplications.

Comment: @WimC I wanted you to post it as answer so that I can upvote it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $z=r_1 cis\theta$ and $w=r_2cis\phi$

$|z+w|^2+|z-w|^2$
$=|(r_1\cos\theta+r_2\cos\phi)+i(r_1\sin\theta+r_2\sin\phi)|^2+|(r_1\cos\theta-r_2\cos\phi)+i(r_1\sin\theta-r_2\sin\phi)|^2$
$=(r_1\cos\theta+r_2\cos\phi)^2+(r_1\sin\theta+r_2\sin\phi)^2+(r_1\cos\theta-r_2\cos\phi)^2+(r_1\sin\theta+r_2\sin\phi)^2$
$=2(r_1^2+r_2^2)=2(|z|^2+|w|^2)$

---

Alternatively,

If $z=x+iy$ and $w=a+ib$

$|z+w|^2+|z-w|^2$
$=|(x+a)+i(y+b)|^2+|(x-a)+i(y-b)|^2$
$=(x+a)^2+(y+b)^2+(x-a)^2+(y-b)^2$
$=2(x^2+y^2+a^2+b^2)=2(|z|^2+|w|^2)$

Comment: @doniyor, welcome. Please have a look into the edited answer?

Comment: yeah, i saw it. i am learning the properties now. thank you so much, you explained better than the book :)

Answer (score 2):

On request: Use $|x|^2 = x \cdot \overline{x}$ and distribute all the multiplications.

Comment: yes. +1 for nice answer